# Why need main method in order to use arraylist methods in the class?

Tags: java, arraylist

**I can do this:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String args[]){

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    myList.add("S");

    }
}
```

**However I CANNOT do this:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Array {

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    myList.add("S");


}
```

**Why I have to include the main method?**

Comment: you have to set them always in a method..

Comment: You don't need a main method... You need a method. The main method is *needed* in order to run the program (and to compile it too, since java 7).

Comment: thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because Java classes consist of methods and blocks. You can't have a raw statement like

```
myList.add("S");
```

Finally, your application needs an [Entry point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java) and the Java Virtual Machine starts by invoking `main()` as documented by [JLS-12.1.4. Invoke `Test.main`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

> Finally, after completion of the initialization for class `Test` (during which other consequential loading, linking, and initializing may have occurred), the method `main` of `Test` is invoked.
>
> The method main must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must specify a formal parameter ([§8.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)) whose declared type is array of `String`.

Comment: ...but you can have `ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();` outside a method for member declarations.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils That creates a field. And you could have an initializer block `{myList.add("S");}` (but that would be copied into every constructor).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can I create an arraylist can holds different types of values? Such as an arrayList that holds integer and string?

Comment: @taimeili123 That isn't a great idea, they don't share a common ancestor except `Object` (so it would have to be a `List<Object>` which isn't very type safe). Then you would have to check whether a particular `Object` is an `Integer` or a `String`.

Answer (score 4):

You need `main` because is the convention from where the program starts. The program cannot know what does or why exist a class so it works only when you using it inside the `main` by convention it's the starting point.