# ArrayList errors

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have a code

```
 class testArrayList
{
   ArrayList<String> auto = new ArrayList<String>();

   auto.add("MITSUBISHI");
   auto.add("Hyundae");
   auto.add("Ford");
   auto.add("Ferrari");
   auto.add("Mazda");
   auto.add("Mustang");
   auto.add("Lamborghini");

   for(String cars : auto)
   {
      System.out.println(cars);
   }
}
```

but when I compiled it, theres an error saying 
[image]

Im confused why it has an error saying **IDENTIFIER EXPECTED or ILLEGAL START OF TYPE** tho I already imported `import java.util.ArrayList;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code as below. You need to add array list inside to the main method.

```
public class testArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> auto = new ArrayList<String>();

    auto.add("MITSUBISHI");
    auto.add("Hyundae");
    auto.add("Ford");
    auto.add("Ferrari");
    auto.add("Mazda");
    auto.add("Mustang");
    auto.add("Lamborghini");

    for(String cars : auto)
    {
        System.out.println(cars);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: why is that I need to put it in the main method sir?

Comment: Answer is with this question. please read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553538/why-need-main-method-in-order-to-use-arraylist-methods-in-the-class

Answer (score 1):

You can put logic ONLY inside methods. The main-method is the method that will be executed when u run the program. You can only put declarations and methods inside a class, thats why you get the runtime errors. I won't do a duplicate, just take Anuradha's solution.

Answer (score 0):

auto is not a keyword and it’s fine in java. Change theSyntax of arrayList it to something

```
List<String> auto= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Did you change that everywhere ?

Comment: but when I put it in main class the error gone why is that?

Comment: Try this  List<String> autoList = new ArrayList<>() , This should work normally in main or any where .

Comment: why is that sir when I put it in main the error is gone? but if it is in another class there is an error?

Comment: Can you confirm the above syntax by putting in normal place where you tried?

Comment: it is still an error sir however if I put it in the main method it works perfectly fine